# proving product topology induced by Discrete Topology and Usual topology equal to this topology

Tags: general-topology

While solving assignment questions of my topology course , I am unable to solve this particular question and so posting it here.

Let $\leq_R$ denote the usual order on $\mathbb{R}$ , let $\leq$ denote the dictionary order on $\mathbb{R}^2$ determined by $\leq_R$ and let U denote the order topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ determined by $\leq$. Furthermore ,$T_1$ denote the discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$ , let $T_2$ denote the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$, and let T denote the product  topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ determined by $T_1$ and $T_2$. Prove that U=T.

First I have to write T ,which will be generated by { r,(a,b) | r,a,b $\in \mathbb{R}$ }.

Let X$\in $U.So, X is of the form $(x_1, x_2)$ and I have to prove that X $\in $ T.but the elements in T are given by  { r,(a,b) | r,a,b $\in \mathbb{R}$ } and we can see that 2nd element there is an interval so, do I have to prove that $x_2$ lies in that interval?

It is my humble request that can you please prove 1 side of the proof that If X$\in $U then how can I show that X $\in $T.

I would do 2nd part by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T$ has a base $\mathscr{B}$ consisting of all sets of the form $B(a,b,c)=\{a\}\times(b,c)$, where $a,b,c\in\Bbb R$, and $b<c$. Each of these sets belongs to $U$, since

$$B(a,b,c)=\left\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:\langle a,b\rangle<\langle x,y\rangle<\langle a,c\rangle\right\}$$

is an open interval in the order $\le$. Thus, $T\subseteq U$.

One way to show that $U\subseteq T$ is to show that the sets $B(a,b,c)$ are also a base for $U$. You can do it by showing that every open interval in the order $\le$ is a union of such sets. Consider the open interval $V$ with endpoints $\langle a,b\rangle$ and $\langle c,d\rangle$, with $\langle a,b\rangle\le\langle c,d\rangle$. There are two possibilities.

- If $a=c$, check that $V=B(a,b,d)$.
- If $a<c$, verify that $$V=\big(\{a\}\times(b,\to)\big)\cup\bigcup_{a<x<c}\big(\{x\}\times\Bbb R\big)\cup\big(\{c\}\times(\leftarrow,d)\big)\,,$$ and show how to write this set as a union of members of $\mathscr{B}$.

**Note:** The notations $(b,\to)$ and $(\leftarrow,d)$ are a less common standard notation equivalent to the more familiar notations $(b,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,d)$.